# Creating UI element at runtime

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to create some buttons at runtime. I tried to find a solution online, but there were only old threads. The only thing I've found is the following code:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)Resource.Layout.Main;

Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.Text = "text";
btn.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
layout.AddView(btn);
```

I don't understand how this should work. There are no compile errors, but the app closes instantly after launching. Can you explain why this happens and how to write this code properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup)Resource.Layout.Main;
```

Won't give you the currently inflated layout. `Resource.Layout.Main` is just an `int` pointing at a resource.

Instead give your currently shown layout and id:

```
android:id="@+id/root"
```

Now it does matter what type it is. The default templates use LinearLayout. So finding it would be:

```
var root = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.root);
```

Then you can add your button to that:

```
var button = new Button(this) 
{ 
    Text = "hello",
    LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
};

root.AddView(button);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll check it later :]